# Emacs connects to system bus, but not to the session one

Tags: emacs, dbus

The system bus works fine

```
(dbus-init-bus :system)
```

returns nil, as it should.

However, connection to the session bus

```
(dbus-init-bus :session)
```

raises

```
(dbus-error "No connection to bus" :session)
```

`qdbus` in the command line works just fine with both buses. It even
works from within eshell, if that is of any concern.

Neither `emacs` nor `emacs --daemon` connect.

Comment: Seems to work fine with `24.5.1`.

Comment: Do you solve this problem? I have the same problem but only on `emacs --daemon` on version `24.3.1` on Linux. BTW, some users pointed that: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2d4c1m/emacs_daemon_dbus_error_no_connection_to_bus/

Comment: @ManoelVilela upgrade your emacs.

Comment: Sorry, I mistype my emacs version here. I meant: `25.3.1`. Trying version 27...

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Emacs are you using? [One version](https://github.com/tovbinm/emacs-24-mac/blob/master/src/dbusbind.c#L790) (before [2012-05-25](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/src/dbusbind.c?id=3529b1c7ecb6ba430902aca1bb6337cfb263916f)) only looks for the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable, while [a more recent one](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/dbusbind.c?id=8b77f61c706e94a1c30ebd697eece6343ff55116#n1092) uses a library function that also looks in `~/.dbus/session-bus` I think.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this before running emacs:
   
   `eval $(dbus-launch)
   export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`